# Should i cast different?

Tags: c, casting

I have this C code(Is not for PC. Is 8bit microcontroller, CCS Compiler)

```
long SirenVolt;//unsigned int16
long long DummyVolt;//unsigned int32

DummyVolt=read_adc();//Function always get values from 0 to 1024
SirenVolt=(long long)((493*DummyVolt)/100);
```

The last line should be cast as long instead?
I need that SirenVolt gets an unsigned int16(long, according the CCS Compiler)
[image]

Comment: The result will already be `long long` because `DummyVolt` is `long long`, and an arithmetic expression uses the longest datatype of the components.'

Comment: In 64-bit CPU long and long long are 8 bytes long. It would not change anything but makes sense to do.If you are using 32-bit CPU long long can not be stored to long.

Comment: If you would have to cast here, it would be too late. The potential overflow would already have happened.

Comment: If `SirenVolt` needs to be `long`, then yes, you should cast the result to `long`. Otherwise you will get a compiler warning. But, if the result may not fit in a `long`, you will lose information. Based on the 2 comments in the code, looks to me like you are porting Java to C.

Comment: The comments (`unsigned int16` and `unsigned int32`) could be removed if you used the actual types `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` - but - those types do not match `long` and `long long`. Either the types you use are wrong or the comments are wrong.

Comment: @Savrona Both long and long long having eight bytes is not true for all systems. Windows remained with 32-bit long even on 64-bit system.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve. With `SirenVolt=((493*DummyVolt)/100);`, the compiler may print a warning that the result is implicitly casted to `long` which may change its value. With `SirenVolt=(long)((493*DummyVolt)/100);` you make this implicit cast explicit, which may result in a different warning of your compiler (or some static code analysis). You might have to add a check that the result actually fits in a `long`. I'm not sure if there is a compiler where `long` is 16 bits, but contrary to the `unsigned` in your comments, the data types are `signed`.

Comment: @Bodo `long` cannot ever be 16 bits (`int` can) – the standard defines a minimum numeric range for long to be covered that requires at least 32 bits.

Comment: @Bodo Done. Please re read the question.

Comment: @Savrona I just edited the question; please re read.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why? The DummyVolt is 32 bit wide.

Comment: @E_Blue A `long long` is never an `unsigned int32` and a `long` is never an `unsigned int16`

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is in CCS compiler.(8 bit microcontroller)

Comment: @E_Blue Doesn't matter if it's compliant. A `long` and a `long long` are both signed types and the manual for that compiler says "_All normal C data types are supported_"

Comment: @JimRhodes Is a CCS compiler. (8bit microcontroller) and doesn't have the standard C types for PC. long in CCS is an unsigned int16 and in regular C is completely different, that's why I added the comments.

Comment: It does have this note that supports what you are saying: "_All types, default are unsigned. [PCD] All types, except float char, by default are signed._"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237374/discussion-between-e-blue-and-ted-lyngmo).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just added a capture from the CCS manual.

Comment: What bad defaults! Is there no other, more compliant compiler? Which target do you have? -- Anyway, the cast in your last line should be `(long)`, as this is what can be stored in `SirenVolt`. According to your comments, it cannot get outside of [0...5048] and fits in a `int16`.

Comment: It is still unclear why you want to use an explicit cast. To avoid a compiler warning? Or what else do you want to achieve? If you want/need to cast the result of your calculation, then cast it to the target data type, i.e. `(long)`. Even if the data types are `unsigned` by default, which is confusing for experienced C programmers, you should not rely on this but make it explicit by using `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` or, if the actual size is important, better use data types that specify the size like `unsigned int16`. Please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: @Bodo The size matter because is an 8bit microcontroller with less than 4KB of RAM, so I must take care of variable's size or is going to take a lot of resources. I can't just define all variables as int64 as most PC programmer do wasting resources like there's no tomorrow. So I'm trying to get better arithmetic because if I try to preform 1024*493 I will get 504832 which is way more than an int16 can hold. So the math is done in 32bits and cast to 16bits.

Comment: @E_Blue A `long` is defined to be at least 32 bits by the C standard. I see no reason why they made it 16. They could have use a plain `int` - and it would have been compliant.

Comment: @E_Blue I don't suggest to use `int64` for all variables but to use `unsigned int16` or `unsigned int32` instead of `long` or `long long` respectively. This will make your program easier to understand for an average C programmer who might expect `long` to be something like `int32_t` (`signed int32` in terms of this strange compiler) or bigger.

Comment: @Bodo OK. I'm trying to do that on new codes but this is from 2011, when I started with this compiler and the code is huge, about 23K lines of code, so if I change something I must change all, as I see it at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should i cast different?

Yes, `SirenVolt` is a `long` and you cast to a `long long`.

The default being `unsigned` and `long` being 16 bit is a bit confusing. It doesn't support `unsigned int64` either.

From the chat:

> `read_adc()` function returns an `unsigned int16`

And since it returns max `1024`, this should work:

```
long SirenVolt = (long) (read_adc() * 493LL / 100);
```

If the compiler doesn't support `LL`:

```
static const long long mul = 493;
static const long long div = 100;

long SirenVolt = (long) (read_adc() * mul / div);
```

`read_adc() * mul` makes a `long long`, max `504832`, divided by `100` max `5048`, fits fine in an `unsigned int16` (the `long`).